# can onload attribute replace $(window).load(...)?

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a table with a dynamic number of sliders, for which I'd need to execute some javascript code for each cell of the table, when the page is loaded. Each slider needs a separate `$(window).load(function(){...` call.

Problem is: I only know the id and parameters at the time the slider is printed to the html, so I cannot add them all in the headers. This ends me up with stuff like

```
<td>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){$("#my_id").PPSlider({ARGUMENTS});};
 </script>
 <input type="hidden" id="my_id"/>
</td>
```

Is there a way to replace this with an `onload` attribute of input? I have tried a dozen ways and they all don't seem to work. If not, how should this be done properly, given that I cannot incorporate them in the header?

EDIT: clarification: the arguments are different for each slider, they represent text to be shown when the slider is in certain positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them classes instead - those don't have to be unique, and this is what they're made for! Also, you should handle `ready` instead.

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_id" class="slider" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').PPSlider({ARGUMENTS});
});
```

Of course, if each slider actually needs its own for some reason (different arguments for each that absolutely can't be determined using attributes? Unlikely, but...) then you can just put the `<script>` *after* the slider element, and then you don't even have to wait for `onload`.

Comment: The arguments are different for each slider, so I'm afraid that won't work. :-(
They represent the text to be shown when the slider is at certain positions. And thanks for the ready-hint!

Comment: @user1111929: Ah. Can you put them in `data-` attributes, or is the `<input>` rendered by something completely different?

Comment: Hmm... interesting. On first sight it should work, but one thing is not clear to me: can one pass string arrays (of variable length) to javascript in this way? E.g. slider 1 has parameters `["yes","sometimes","no"]` and slider 2 has parameters `["1","2","3","4","5","6+"]`. All examples that I find are just regular strings or numbers.

Comment: @user1111929: You could just make them comma-separated, or use JSON, but may as well just add the `<script>`s in that case. Sorry.